# Can't connect Edge Impulse project from Raspberry pi 3

Tags: raspberry-pi-os

[image: ![enter image description here]
I wanted to connect the edge impulse audio classifier model from raspberry pi 2 and OS I am using is Raspbian lite.

I got an error,
[SER] Using microphone hw:1,0
Failed to initialize Linux tool Error code was not 0: Probing devices...

[0:15:05.824831212] [938]  INFO Camera camera_manager.cpp:293 libcamera v0.0.0+3156-f4070274
Failed to start device monitor!

Could anyone help me to understand what is actually error message trying to say?

Comment: The pi doesn't have a mic and do you have a camera connected?

Comment: USB mic was connected but not the camera. My model supposes to detect audio. There was no use of camera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need a camera, use:

```
    edge-impulse-linux --disable-camera
```